# where class's entity reference is null but call a local function of this class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
for (int i = 0; i < hurtNumberList.Count; i++)
{
    _hurtNumber = hurtNumberList[i].hurtNumber;
    if(_hurtNumber == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("hurtNumber canot be null!!");
    }
    if(!_master)
    {
        _hurtNumber.DestroyHurtNumber();
    }
    else
    {
        float time = Time.time;
        float timeD = time - hurtNumberList[i].startTime;
        if(timeD > 0 && timeD <= hurtNumberList[i].durationTime && _hurtNumber.bStart &&
            hurtNumberList[i].startMoveTime > 0 && Time.time >= hurtNumberList[i].startMoveTime)
        {
            SetLocaltion(hurtNumberList[i]);
        }

        if(timeD >= hurtNumberList[i].durationTime && _hurtNumber.bStart)
        {
            _hurtNumber.DestroyHurtNumber();
        }
    }
    if(!_hurtNumber.bStart)
        delIndexList.Add(i);
}
public void DestroyHurtNumber()
{
    bStart = false;
    isDie = true;
    Queue<UIHurtNumber> pool = GetPool(this.GetType().ToString());
    //DebugUtility.Log("回收池内的:" + this.GetType().ToString());
    if (pool.Count < 8)
    {
        pool.Enqueue(this);
        HurtNumaberActive(false);
        return;
    }
    label = null;
    critLabel = null;
    if(this != null && this.gameObject != null)
    {
        Object.Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("222");
    }
}
```

As show above. Where `Debug.Log("hurtNumber canot be null!!")` is print out `"hurtNumber canot be null!!"`, so `_hurtNumber` is to be `null`, but actually the following sentence `_hurtNumber.DestroyHurtNumber()` is also execute. So the `Debug.Log("222")` is also print out `"222"` and with any error in unityEditor. I just want to now why this happen..

Comment: Just to make sure bStart, isDie, label and critlabel  are not static?

Comment: Does the object type in `_hurtNumber` implement the `==` operator?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen `_hurtNumber` is a Unity3D component and yes it overrides == operator.

Comment: Does that `==` operator handle `null` correctly?

Comment: Yes to Unity3D standards. It returns true for `component == null` which has its `gameObject` `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar situation, and it might be same as yours.

From your code I see that `_hurtNumber` is reference to a Unity3D component that derives from `MonoBehaviour`.

It is possible that gameObject to which this component was added was destroyed, but reference to this component was taken previous to destorying the gameObject, and will result in that `_hurtNumber == null` is `true` but you can still access fields, methods, variables of it.

In my case, we were storing reference to the component in static variable and after destroying the scene, the reference was null, but we could access public variables and method of it.

**So basicly component can be null (as there is not gameObject) but the memory reserved for it wasnt freed**.

EDIT:
I found this also on Unity3D forum:
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/why-can-i-still-call-functions-in-destroyed-monobehaviour-objects.307603/

> Just because a GameObject is destroyed does not mean that any C# scripts associated with the GameObject (MonoBehaviours, etc) have been destroyed or garbage collected. As long as something has a reference to the C# object, it will be held in memory and will not be GC'ed. You will be leaking the C# objects until you clear all references to them. It's very important to un-set any delegates or events for this reason. The OnDestroy or OnDisable methods tend to be a good place to do this.
>
> You also noticed that you can't access this.name in the component that
>   has been destroyed. Again, this is because the unmanaged GameObject
>   and component have been destroyed, but the C# object has not. You can
>   check if the unmanaged objects have been destroyed. Unity has
>   overridden the == operator for anything that is a UnityEngine.Object.
>   Thus, it is possible this == null to be true if it's code in a
>   MonoBehaviour for which the GameObject has been destroyed. This is a
>   quirk of Unity; in normal C#, this == null would always be false
>   (unless the operator has been similarly overridden).

More investigation:

The problem seems to sit inside `==` operator for Unity3D components.
http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/16/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it/

> When you get a c# object of type “GameObject”[2](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/16/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it/), it contains almost nothing. this is because Unity is a C/C++ engine. All the actual information about this GameObject (its name, the list of components it has, its HideFlags, etc) lives in the c++ side. The only thing that the c# object has is a pointer to the native object. We call these c# objects “wrapper objects”. The lifetime of these c++ objects like GameObject and everything else that derives from UnityEngine.Object is explicitly managed. These objects get destroyed when you load a new scene. Or when you call Object.Destroy(myObject); on them. Lifetime of c# objects gets managed the c# way, with a garbage collector. This means that it’s possible to have a c# wrapper object that still exists, that wraps a c++ object that has already been destroyed. **If you compare this object to null, our custom == operator will return “true” in this case, even though the actual c# variable is in reality not really null**.